# Updating a CompositeView when an Item is removed from it's collection

Tags: marionette

I have a Marionette.CompositeView. I added the ability to remove an item from an item from the collection in the Composite's item view. The CompositeView displays a summary- which is nothing more than the count of items in it's collection.

What is the best way to update the CompositeView when an item is deleted:

```
app = new Marionette.Application()
app.addRegions
  main: '#main'


app.module 'Views', (views, app)->
  views.MyItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend
    template: '#my-view-template'
    tagName: 'li'
    events:
      'click' : ()->
        @model.collection.remove @model

  views.MyCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend
    itemView: views.MyItemView
    template: '#my-composite-view-template'
    itemViewContainer: 'ul'
    initialize: ()->
      @model = new Backbone.Model
        count: @collection.length
      @collection.on 'remove', ()->
        console.log 'remove'

app.on 'start', ->
  app.main.show new app.Views.MyCompositeView
    collection: new Backbone.Collection [
      new Backbone.Model( foo: 'bar')
      new Backbone.Model( foo: 'bar')
      new Backbone.Model( foo: 'bar')                                  
    ]

$ ()->
  app.start()
```

and here is the html

```
  <div  id="main">Hello world</div>

  <script type='htm/text' id='my-view-template'>
  I am dynamic <em><%= foo %></em>
  </script>

  <script type='html/text' id='my-composite-view-template'>
    <div id='counter'><%= count %></div>
    <ul></ul>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection and composite views will rerender child item views (and/or remove individual item views). In your case, you want to rerender the *entire* composite view when the collection is added to or subtracted from. For that purpose, bind the render method to the appropriate collection events in your view definition:

```
collectionEvents: {
  "add": "render",
  "remove": "render"
}
```

Comment: Hi David... that's not the issue-- the problem is that I want to update the count which is connected to the model on the parent (composite) view. I know I can do it by grabbing the element and resetting it's value-- i just thought there might be a better way (re-render or something like that)

Comment: I knew your name was familiar-- purchased your book awhile back-- it was excellent. Finally warming up to Marionette.

Comment: Glad you liked it! Shameless plug: I'll be publishing an advanced book (https://leanpub.com/marionette-serious-progression/) in the next few days...